# Loading data into List using store sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have created navigaton view using Sencha touch 2. Navigation view has list component which i want to load it using store and model. I created model and store as required. On running my app the list does not render any data. 
It also gives warning in conolse `[Ext.dataview.List#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found`  . I am not sure what this error means.
Here is my mvc code,

model:

```
Ext.define('GS.model.BlogModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'title', type: 'auto'},
        {name: 'author', type: 'auto'},
        {name: 'content', type:'auto'}
      ]
    }
});
```

store:

```
Ext.define('GS.store.blogs',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',
config:{
    model:'GS.model.BlogModel',
    autoLoad :true,
    proxy:{
                type:'jsonp',
                url:'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
                reader:{
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty:'responseData.feed.entries'
                }
            }
}
});
```

view:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Blog',{
extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype:'blog',
requires:[
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
    'Ext.data.Store',
    'GS.store.blogs'
],
config: {
    title:'Blog',
    iconCls:'star',
    items:{
        xtype:'list',
        itemTpl:'{title}',
        title:'Recent Posts',
        store:'GS.store.blogs'
    }

}
});
```

Can someone point me out what is missing/
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `store` property in `items` for your list needs to be an instance, not the name of the class. `GS.store.blogs` is the class name. You need to create an instance of this class using `Ext.create` and pass that instance in `items`. Oh yeah, and your syntax for `items` is wrong too. Needs to be an array `[]` not an object `{}`. So something like:

```
var blogsStore = Ext.create("GS.store.blogs"); //put this in the items list

Ext.define('GS.view.Blog',{
    extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype:'blog',
    requires:[
        'Ext.dataview.List',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.Store',
        'GS.store.blogs'
    ],
    config: {
        title:'Blog',
        iconCls:'star',
        items:[{
            xtype:'list',
            itemTpl:'{title}',
            title:'Recent Posts',
            store: blogsStore //Store instance here. And items are in array, not Object
         }]

    }
});
```

Comment: Ext.create will create a new instance of my store. If I want to use my same store every where then I have to add it to app.js `stores:['blogs']` which i was missing. Also `store:'GS.store.blogs'` I changed to 'store:'blogs'' which works fine now.

Comment: This warning `[Ext.dataview.List#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found` got resolved by adding `requires:['GS.model.BlogModel']` in blogs store.

Comment: I create the store instance once, then use `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup` to use the same store everywhere. Good to know your way works too; I've learned something new :)