# Sencha Touch 2 - My Ext.List doesnt appear

Tags: store, sencha-touch-2

Here's my App code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'ProjectName',
    appFolder: APP_URL + "app",

    // phoneStartupScreen: 'LOGO.png',

    controllers: ['Site_inside'],
    views: ['Inside_spotlist'],
    models: ['Spot'],
    stores: ['Spots'],

    launch: function() {
        //bootstrap
        console.log("inner site bootstrap");

        //var spotlist = Ext.create("ProjectName.view.Inside_spotlist");

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xclass: 'ProjectName.view.Inside_spotlist'
        });

        return true;   
    }
});
```

View 'Inside_spotlist' code:

```
Ext.define('ProjectName.view.Inside_spotlist', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    alias: 'spotlist',
    xtype: 'spotlist',

    requires: [
        'ProjectName.store.Spots'
    ],

    config: {
        store: 'Spots',
        itemTpl: '{first_name} {last_name}'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log("spolist loaded");
    }
});
```

The code of 'Spot' model:

```
Ext.define("ProjectName.model.Spot", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'firstName',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'lastName',
                type:'string'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

And finally, the Spots store:

```
Ext.define("ProjectName.store.Spots", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        listeners: {
            load: function() {
                console.log("loaded store");
            }
        },

        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,

        model: 'ProjectName.model.Spot',
        data:[
            {
                firstName: 'test',
                lastName:  'test2'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

It loads fine (console messages appears, no error or warning messages), but the list with my test data does not appear. If I try to "grab" the site up and down, the right side iOS-style scrollbar shows, but there are no data in the list.

What's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this :

```
Ext.Viewport.add(
    Ext.create('ProjectName.view.Inside_spotlist')
);
```

instead of this :

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xclass: 'ProjectName.view.Inside_spotlist'
});
```

additionally....

you can try this :

```
config: {
    store: 'ProjectName.store.Spots',
    itemTpl: '{first_name} {last_name}'
}
```

instead of this :

```
config: {
    store: 'Spots',
    itemTpl: '{first_name} {last_name}'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you follow the convention described here: [Loading data into List using store sencha touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958949/loading-data-into-list-using-store-sencha-touch-2/9962250#9962250)

Although the comments in that answer seem to indicate that the person who asked the question was doing it your way, I'm not sure how that works. Try doing it the way it's described in the answer i.e. make an instance of the store using `Ext.create` and thereafter use `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup` to find and use that instance wherever you need it. Your problem here is that the `store` property in your list doesn't have an instance of your store.