# Display data from a php file in sencha touch2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can I display data from a php file using sencha touch2 ?

Comment: I got a working solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958949/loading-data-into-list-using-store-sencha-touch-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to achieve it but for me I will make use of json and `Ext.ajax.request`

For example my `example.php` look simple like this:

```
$array = array(
    "go" => true,
    "message" => "Thank you for your message",
);
```

As I have said, I'm using json so I will need to encode the `$array` to retrieve it in view later

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Then in your view you can get the data from php file using `Ext.util.JSONP.request()` but here I will handle it by `Ext.Ajax.request()` so:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  values : paramValues // values that you want to pass to example.php
  url: 'example.php',

  success: function(response) {
      //Here you need to decode the json data
      var data    = Ext.decode(response.responseText)
          go      = data.go,
          message = data.message;
      console.log(message); //Thank you for your message
  }

  failure: function(response) {
      console.log(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

This maybe not the best way and possible have mistakes but at least I hope that it will be useful :)

Comment: I tried your code, but I am getting an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'request' of undefined NotesListContainer.js:2
(anonymous function)

Comment: Above is just a sample code and it works fine for me. I don't know about your currently code so maybe you need to customize it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

create a JSON store and set url to php file. In the php file echo the response using json_encode();